# Plot vs. Lore tags - do we need the distinction?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

In asking the chat room whether the [plot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot) tag would be appropriate for [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28722/if-the-nuclear-holocaust-happened-in-2077-then-why-are-the-clothes-and-music-in), we [briefly discussed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/conversation/plot-vs-lore-tag) which tag would be appropriate, [plot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot) or [lore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lore) and whether or not they needed to be distinct.

We have 49 questions tagged [plot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot) and 7 questions tagged [lore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lore). I've never seen any seriously problematic questions in either tag, but do we need a separate tag for "lore"? While there are subtle differences between the two, do we anticipate the use case for these 2 tags being distinct enough from each other to keep them as separate tags? Or should we just merge them?

Comment: If you're going to merge them, I'd call it something else like `[story]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I agree that the two tags are similar, I don't think that they can simply be merged. I see *more* of a case for removing [lore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lore) outright, but I'm reluctant to do that blindly.

The issue is a simple one: How do we handle a question about a game-world that *isn't* related to the plot? Asking [Why are there are no tanks in Fallout?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18748/why-are-there-no-tanks-in-fallout-3-new-vegas) isn't an important plot point in the game -- it never comes up -- but that doesn't mean it's not an interesting question.

Some games have the benefit of having an established game universe, in which case a better choice might be [game-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-series) rather than [game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) and [lore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lore), as evidenced by the [portal-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portal-series) and [half-life-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life-series) tags. (There's even a [fallout-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-series) that the New Vegas question might benefit from)

I think the best course of action may be to simply remove the [lore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lore) tag entirely. Though it doesn't have a tag wiki, **I** would define Lore to be any question focusing on the plot and background of a specific game, or a suite of games. In the case where there is only a single relevant game under discussion (such as [this Terraria question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26274/does-terraria-have-any-lore)), it is okay to use only the game tag. Popular *franchises*, on the other hand, would benefit from a [game-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-series) tag instead, as they may be relevant to more than a single game.

Comment: What do you think of @NickT's suggestion of merging them into [tag:story]? That would likely cover both [tag:plot] and [tag:lore] scenarios, I'd think. I agree that nuking [tag:lore] seems like a good idea, which I assume you'd be able to do through your super-silent mod powers now.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes Hm. Story appears to currently be a synonym for plot. Let's see if I can figure out how to reversify that.

Comment: My comment wasn't really meant as pro-merge (or anti-), but to use a more general term if you do