# Should a tag like [plot] be brought back?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed recently that Arqade doesn't have a tag like [plot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot) or [lore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lore) anymore. I searched meta in an attempt to find a burnination effort and couldn't find one; this is the closest I was able to find: [Plot vs. Lore tags - do we need the distinction?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2700/plot-vs-lore-tags-do-we-need-the-distinction) - A synonym proposal that turned into a burnination on what was ultimately less than 60 questions.

Personally, I don't think these questions should be considered "meta tags" in the same way that is discussed in the blog post: [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). In that blog post, Aaronut said:

> **The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question.** They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, or generally what “kind” of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.).

I disagree that [plot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot) and [lore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lore) are meta tags under that definition. The question contains content that is not about the gameplay of a game, or [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) of a game (which, as of this posting, is the #10 most asked tag on this Stack). *If technical-issues ought to be a tag, then so should plot.*

At the very least, even if this question / proposal gets massively downvoted, hopefully it can stick around as a signpost if anyone ever decides to ask this question again. **Let's bring back [plot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot)**!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there's a little bit of a miscommunication going on here. Someone (maybe even me?) brought up meta tags in the middle of a conversation about [lore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lore). But I agree with you, [lore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lore) is not technically a meta tag. It does describe the contents of the question.

However, that doesn't make it a good tag. The tag didn't serve any meaningful purpose. A question tagged with [diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3) and also with [lore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lore) is still only answerable by experts in Diablo 3.

Tags are supposed to indicate *areas of expertise*. Therefore, the [lore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lore) tag would presuppose that one could be an expert in "lore".

That's ludicrous, though. There is no such thing as being an expert in *all* lore from *all* video game universes.

In this way, even though the [lore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lore) tag isn't *technically* a meta tag, it would be *used* as a meta tag. The tag itself isn't meaningful, and you can't be an expert in its contents, so it's just noise on the question.

Comment: But I suppose you *can* be an expert in [tag:technical-issues] across all games, then?

Comment: @durron597 There are actually a lot of common causes for technical-issues across myriad different games. Although, if you were asking me, we'd just ban that whole category of questions wholesale :)

Comment: It is better to argue for something on its own merits rather than pointing at somewhere else on the site and saying "But what about this tag?" A lot of us would be happy if [tag:technical-issues] was gone too. If you say a thing should exist because something similar exists, you really need to justify the existence of the similar thing, too, not immediately assume that everyone will just say, "Oh, okay then, you got me."

Comment: I mean, if a game has a bug that causes your save file to get corrupted, that is both a [tag:technical-issues] and one that you really can't know much about unless you've played the game...

Comment: Also [achievements]. Both tech issues & achievements tags are a little different however - People mark this tags as 'ignored' so that questions with them don't show up on the front page for them. (Actually come to think of it, having a [lore] tag **would** stop a lot of the complaining from people :P)

Comment: Is there a way to allow tags just in dependency to another one? I like the [Diablo-3] + [lore] example. What if I wanna ask if a part of a book is available in one of the 3 Diablo games? I would like to tag it [Diablo] + [lore] instead of [diablo] + [diablo-2] + [diablo-3]

Comment: @Nitro.de - If asking about the overall universe of Diabolo, you would use [tag:diablo-series]

Comment: @Robotnik That's an excellent reason to have the tag, actually.

Comment: @durron597 I couldn't disagree more. We shouldn't have a tag *specifically* so people can ignore it.

Comment: There's no way to browse lore questions without a tag for it, since searching the text of the questions won't work well. Not every lore question uses the word "lore". If nobody here cares about that, then that's fine, but a tag could help in searching questions.